# Button ng drop down- how to choose the item using webdriver with java

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a button with drop down item,
if i click the button it's open the list and choose the item
below is the html

```
<button id="btn-append-to-body" class="btn btn-primary mobile-quick-button dropdown-toggle" type="button" uib-dropdown-toggle="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<div class="clearfix">
<span class="pull-left text-left ng-binding" tabindex="0">   Select one </span>
<span class="pull-right text-right ng-binding">
</div>
</button>
<ul class="uib-dropdown-menu dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body">
<!-- ngRepeat: option in dropOptions -->
<li id="quickOption" class="ng-scope" role="presentation" name="quickOption" ng-repeat="option in dropOptions" ng-click="selectOption(option)" required="" tabindex="0" style="">
<a href="">
<div class="clearfix">
<span class="pull-left ng-binding">frame number</span>
</div>
</a>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: option in dropOptions -->
<li id="quickOption" class="ng-scope" role="presentation" name="quickOption" ng-repeat="option in dropOptions" ng-click="selectOption(option)" required="" tabindex="0">
<a href="">
<div class="clearfix">
<span class="pull-left ng-binding">serial number</span>
</div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to choose any one of the item from this list,

```
public void lookupSearch (String item){
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='btn-append-to-body']")).click();
//then i choose/click the parameter item (i.e frame number or serial number)
}
```

passing the item as parameter

please guide me how should i choose the item

Answer (score 1):

To click on the button with drop down item and choose any one of the item from this list you can use the following code block :

```
public void lookupSearch (String item)
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='btn-append-to-body']/div/span[contains(.,'Select one')]")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait4elements = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    List<WebElement> myElements = wait4elements.until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfElementsToBe(By.xpath("//ul[@class='uib-dropdown-menu dropdown-menu']/li/a/div/span"), 2));
    for(WebElement elem:myElements)
        if(elem.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains(item))
        {
            elem.click();
            break;
        }
    System.out.println("Element with text as "+ item +" is selected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below is the answer from ul find the Li count, then getting each li text and compare with `item` string

```
WebElement uList = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='quick-search-dropdown']/ul"));
            List<WebElement> listCount = uList.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
            for (int i = 1; i <= listCount.size(); i++) {
                WebElement lookupItem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//li[@id='quickOption']/a/div/span[1])[" + i + "]"));
                String lookupItemValue = lookupItem.getText();
                if (lookupItemValue.equalsIgnoreCase(Item)) {
                    lookupItem.click();
                }
            }
```